# Нужна помощь с расшифровкой регулярок

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Есть код на JS

```
 var strongRegex = new RegExp("^(?=.{8,})(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*\\W).*$", "g");
 var mediumRegex = new RegExp("^(?=.{8,})(((?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z]))|((?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9]))|((?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[0-9]))).*$", "g");
 var enoughRegex = new RegExp("(?=.{8,}).*", "g");
```

`enoughRegex` - смотрит чтобы было не меньше 8 символов тут ясно
`mediumRegex` - не меньше 8 символов и большая и маленькая буква или большая и цифра или маленькая и цифра
`strongRegex` - не меньше 8 символов и большая и маленькая и цифра. Но что значит `(?=.*\\W)`?

Так же не пойму что значит `.*$", "g"` вконце. Помогите понять, нужно переписать на РНР.
Да и вообще, может кто-то знает более крутой способ проверки сложности пароля? Чтобы можно было юзануть и на js и на php ? Буду рад помощи!

Comment: `\W matches any non-word character (equal to [^a-zA-Z0-9_])`

Comment: `$` обозначает конец строки, однако с предшествующей `.*` смысла в нем нет никакого

Comment: а g - флаг global. говорит искать все вхождения по всей строке.

Comment: благодарю вас всех! сделайте ответ чтобы я его смог выбрать

Comment: разберитесь, сварганьте классный ответ, а мы вас с удовольствием заплюсуем.